# Split fields from a Cypher query with the Python language

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm using py2neo with the following script:

```
query=
"MATCH p = (:Task {ID:'1', nick: 'marco1'})-
[:RELATIONSHIP*]->(:Task{ID:'19', nick: 'gio1'}) 
WITH p, REDUCE(x = 0, a IN NODES(p) | x + a.duration) AS cum_duration 
ORDER BY cum_duration DESC LIMIT 1 RETURN p"

criticalPath = myGraph.run(query)
for i in criticalPath:
  print(i)
```

I need to get the values of "ID" and "nick" from this query and save these values in Python variables, how should I do? Please, might you help me? it's very important thank you in advance

Comment: You have a REDUCE() function in there that isn't being used or aliased, so this won't compile. Can you fix that first, or remove it if it isn't needed, or at least clarify what you're trying to do here? Also, what data do you want out of this? Just those properties for all the nodes in each path?

Comment: It's the cumulative duration, in order to calculate the critical path, cf. https://neo4j.com/graphgist/8e1d6ff9-f7fa-4c99-9c5d-ecb94ba46d81 query 5

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the ID and nick properties of the nodes in the critical path, then return a collection of map values for each node in the path:

```
MATCH p = (:Task {ID:'1', nick: 'marco1'})-
[:RELATIONSHIP*]->(:Task{ID:'19', nick: 'gio1'}) 
WITH p, REDUCE(x = 0, a IN NODES(p) | x + a.duration) AS cum_duration 
ORDER BY cum_duration DESC 
LIMIT 1 
RETURN [node in nodes(p) | node {.ID, .nick}] as critPath
```

The return uses a shorthand form of the EXTRACT() function, and map projection to only return maps of the ID and nick properties of each node in the path.